# Cannot view any Test Suites and Test Cases in TFS 2013 Web Access despite being able to access them in MTM

Tags: tfs, microsoft-test-manager, tfs-web-access

My organization uses TFS 2013, with a split of VS 2012 and VS 2013 for the programmers and testers.

When I try to right click --> open in web access on any of our MTM tests or suites, I get this error:
"The test plan with id 97761 does not exist or it’s area path is not owned by the default project team. Include it in the default project team’s owned areas and try again."

Which leads me to believe that this is a configuration/permissions issue, however our IT could not find what the problem is.

Any ideas? I've heard from team mates that this feature used to work before TFS was upgraded from 2012 to 2013.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We had the same problem, and we finally narrowed it down to a change to how Test Plans work in TFS 2013 Update 3.
In the past test plans were not considered work items, but since TFS 2013 Update 3, they are.

We solved the problem by opening the root test plan as a work item in Visual Studio 2013, and saving it.

Since then, test plan web access no longer throws the error "Test plan with id xxxxx does not exist or its area path is not owned by the default project team."

Comment: Thanks! It appears that editing the base test plan in VS and saving it does indeed fix this issue!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are in the Full Access group in the TFS Web Access Control Panel.  Also make sure you have permissions to the area that the test case/suite/plan belong to.

Comment: I've verified with my IT that I'm in an access group with full permissions except for deletion. I know I have permissions to the area because I wrote the Cases and created the Suite myself in MTM.