# The test plan with id 328 does not exist or it’s area path is not owned by the default project team

Tags: microsoft-test-manager

We are trying to access Test plans using the Web interface from Test Manager 2013 and we keep getting this message.

The test plan with id 328 does not exist or it’s area path is not owned by the default project team.

I read in another post that a fix would be to open the ROOT Test plan in Visual Studio and save it.

I don't know how to do that, can someone please let me know how or point me to somewhere I can learn on how to do that.

Comment: When exactly are you getting this message? When trying select a *Test Suite* or a *Test Case*? Or immediatelly if you change to "Test" area in TFS Web Access?

Comment: from within MTM I right click and select open in web access

Answer (score 0):

I haven't had this problem myself but what another post you mentioned means is following:

- Go to Visual Studio
- Search for a *Work Item* with ID from the error message you are getting (in your case 328)
- Open this *Work Item* (it should be a *Test Plan*) in Visual Studio and save it

According to the post [Cannot view any Test Suites and Test Cases in TFS 2013 Web Access despite being able to access them in MTM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26756790/cannot-view-any-test-suites-and-test-cases-in-tfs-2013-web-access-despite-being) this should solve your problem.

**Update:**

What do you see if you just open TFS Web access in browser?
Can you see this "Test" part?

[image]

Can you see your *Test Plans* in the list of test plans of selected *Team Project"?
If you can't see your *Test Plans* in the list change the *Team Project* (just click on this and select another one)

**Further update:**

Please check this article describing new permissions that was added with *TFS 2013 Update3*: [Plan Manual Tests using Team Web Access](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd380763.aspx)

> You still access test plans and suites using either the Team Web Access or Microsoft Test Manager. **But make sure that you set up access based on permissions for the area path**.

We didn't have this kind of issues after upgrade to *TFS 2013 Update 3* so I can't help you much...

If you don't find nothing helpful in article above consider to contact *Microsoft* since it seems to be an Upgrade issue.

Comment: I have tried this and I get a message stating the work item does not exist. It may be because I don't have permission to open this work item?

I will check with my administrator.

Comment: *Test Plan* is a *work item* since TFS 2013 Update 3. Which version of TFS are you using?

Comment: Hi thanks for answering, I cannot see any test plans from this list although I was able to two weeks ago before the update, I am using TFS 2013 update 3. with Visual Studio

Comment: So, you can't see *Test Plans* in Web access since you have updated to TFS 2013 Update; that's very important information! It sounds it is about missing permissions. Usuallly you don't have such issues after an update, at least if you updated from *TFS 2013 Update 2* to *Update 3*. I would recommend you to contact Microsoft. It is very hard to analyze an upgrade issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a bug in the web access portion of TFS.

If the test plan's area includes a child node, you will get the error.  For example:  myArea/myChildArea.  If you remove the child area, it works in web access.  (Test Manager works in all cases.)  My guess is that the web access logic is comparing the entire area path name as opposed to just looking at the top node of the area path.

(Problem occurs in TFS 2015)

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem and i solved it using following option.

Go to Areas on web tool and enable checkbox for sub-areas which selected under test plan, it is recommended not doing it on root areas.